# CheckedTextView Behaving Erratically

Tags: android-widget

Has anyone else had a problem with CheckedTextView showing multiple checked items when only 1 is checked? When a CheckedTexView item is clicked, the response from the OnClickListener is to check the entries before and after the clicked item.

Here's the code:

```
    mFriendDoneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.doneAddAFriendButton);
    mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contactList);

    populateContactList();

    mListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mListView.setItemsCanFocus(false);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
              int arg2, long arg3) {
            int selectedPosition = arg2;

            CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.friendEntryText);
            String mtext = textView.getText().toString();


            Log.i("AddAFriendActivity", "Click on position "+selectedPosition);

            Toast t = new Toast(AddAFriendActivity.this);
            t = Toast.makeText(AddAFriendActivity.this, "Clicked on  " + arg2+mtext+arg3, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            t.show();

          }
        });
```

private void populateContactList() {
        // Build adapter with contact entries
        Cursor cursor = getContacts();
        String[] fields = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME
        };
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.friend_entry, cursor, fields, new int[] {R.id.friendEntryText});
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

```
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = null;

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

The XML is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem... textView needs to be declared as a field, otherwise the managedQuery results cycle through the onClickListener.